# Unable to write xpath for add to cart in flipkart

Tags: xpath, flipkart-api

I am not able to write xpath for the following code.

I tried `input[@value="Add to Cart" and data-seller-id="0275741dba3346b8"]` but it doesn't work.

```
  <input class="btn-buy-now btn-big disabled current active" type="submit" value="Add to Cart" data-is-listing-buyable="true" data-is-pin-available="false" data-is-pin-serviceable="true" data-is-in-cart="true" data-is-large="false" data-disable-cart="true" data-vertical="carabiner" data-pid="CBRE7GW7PSCGX3VD" data-seller-id="0275741dba3346b8" data-listing-metrics="TO_BE_IMPLEMENTED" data-buy-listing-id="LSTCBRE7GW7PSCGX3VD2BFSP7"/>
```

Comment: you missed '@' before data-seller-id: `...and @data-seller-id="0275741dba3346b8"...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot an `@` at data-seller-id in the XPath-Query-String

```
input[@value="Add to Cart" and @data-seller-id="0275741dba3346b8"]
                               ^
```

Comment: the position of the "add to cart" may change in the future then should i use the parent node for writing xpath?

Comment: That depends on where it will be put in the future. If it would still be an attribute of the `input` element, nothing would change.